# SUM vs EXIST in SqlServer

Tags: sql-server, group-by, having

The intent is to return all 'Unprocessed' TransactionSets if they have NO PaymentUid and NO ProcessStatus.value('/CPI/@ProcessItem)[1]'... relations, and also pick up 'No-Matched-Payments' TransactionSets if they have ANY PaymentUid AND ANY ProcessStatus.value('/CPI/@ProcessItem)[1]'... relations.

The SUM function in the having seem clunky and don't allow SQL to quit when it encounters any or none. So it seems like it's inefficient, and at the very least quite clunky to read and deal with. Is there a way to write this with something like an EXIST ?

```
select ts.TransactionSetUid
  from TransactionSet ts
    join TransactionHeader eh on ts.TransactionSet = eh.TransactionSet
    join TransactionPayment tp on eh.TransactionHeaderUid = tp.TransactionHeaderUid
    left join ServicePayment sp on tp.TransactionPaymentUid = sp.TransactionPaymentUid
  where TransactionStatus in ('Unprocessed', 'No-Matched-Payments')
  group by ts.TransactionSet
  having (TransactionStatus = 'Unprocessed'
      and SUM( CASE WHEN sp.TransactionItem is null THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)  = 0
      and SUM( CASE WHEN tp.ProcessStatus.value('(/CPI/@ProcessItem)[1]', 'varchar(50)') IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) = 0)
    or (ts.RuleStatus = 'No-Matched-Payments'
      and (SUM( CASE WHEN sp.TransactionItem is null THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) <> 0
        or SUM( CASE WHEN tp.ProcessStatus.value('(/CPI/@ProcessItem)[1]', 'varchar(50)') IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) <> 0))
```

UPDATE to answer questions. The relationships between the TransactionSet is one to many with the other tables. There could be many TransactionPayment records but the query is only concerned with ProcessStatus.value that has an xml node at (/CPI/@processItem)[1]. But with ServicePayment, any non-null TransactionItem will do.

As I understand it, the group by is only in there because of the SUM functions. The intent is to flag any TransactionSet that meets one of two conditions.

```
The first condition is:
  the Transaction Status is 'Unprocessed'
  and
    there are no Process Status values
    and
    there are no Transaction Items.

The second condition is:
  the Transaction Status  is 'No-Matched-Payments'
  and
    there is at least one Process Status value
    or
    there is at least one Transaction Item.
```

So the query was set up to use SUM to count the number of times the left join on ServicePayment comes up NULL or when the XML value in TransactionPayment doesn't contain a '/CPI/@processItem'.

It seems to me that instead of using a SUM, the query could instead use an EXIST or some other mechanism to short circuit the test condition. The value of the SUM is not really important, It just needs to know if there is at least one or if there are none.

--
Thank you to everyone: I know i'm not a database expert by any means, and I've been programming in the seven C's (C,C++,C#,Java,etc.) for so long that I sometimes forget that SQL is not an imperative language, or more likely, I just don't think in declarative terms.

Comment: We can't really help here because we have no idea what you are asking. What does "don't allow SQL to quit when it encounters any or none." mean?

Comment: Can you share the schema and sample data? And why do you need to use `group by` when you don't aggregate? A `where` should be enough.

Comment: @SeanLange - presumably, it's a reference to the fact that `EXISTS` can return `true` as soon as it encounters a single matching row. Here, the OP is attempting to "short-circuit" the `SUM` since all they care about is zero or non-zero results (and the SUM is only over values of either `0` or `1`, no negatives, so once it goes over `0` we know what the final result will be)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: Yes, that's exactly correct. The query doesn't need to know how many, just if there is at least one relationship or not.

Comment: "short circuit the test condition" If you're trying to do this with SQL, you're thinking somewhat incorrectly. SQL is a *declarative* language. You specify what you want returned and the query engine determines how to execute it. Even with a subquery, you never fully determine the order of execution. You effectively can't short circuit in SQL like you can in other languages. You might try rewriting the query as a series of EXISTS subqueries, but it may perform worse or might return different results entirely.  Without knowing the data and indexes it's very difficult to say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think something like this should do the trick:

```
select ts.TransactionSetUid
  from TransactionSet ts
  where CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM TransactionHeader eh
       join TransactionPayment tp on eh.TransactionHeaderUid = tp.TransactionHeaderUid
       left join ServicePayment sp on tp.TransactionPaymentUid = sp.TransactionPaymentUid
       where ts.TransactionSet = eh.TransactionSet and
       (
           sp.TransactionItem is not null or
           tp.ProcessStatus.value('(/CPI/@ProcessItem)[1]', 'varchar(50)') IS not NULL
       )
 ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END =
        CASE TransactionStatus
              WHEN 'Unprocessed' THEN 0
              WHEN 'No-Matched-Payments' THEN 1
        END
```

That is, I've put the `EXISTS` check in to test for either condition and put it inside a `CASE` expression so that we don't have to write it out twice for which result we want (for `Unprocessed` and `No-Matched-Payments`).

I've also crafted the second `CASE` expression to return 0, 1 or `NULL` so that if the `TransactionStatus` is something else, it doesn't matter what result the `EXISTS` produces.

I hope I've followed the correct chains of 0/1, true/false, and/or, NULL/NOT NULL logic here - if it's not 100%, it's hopefully just tweaks to those options. I've also assumed I can shift all of the tables except `TransactionSet` into the `EXISTS` - it may be that `TransactionHeader` has to stay outside if that's where `TransactionStatus` is coming from.

If this isn't correct, you should probably add bare-bones tables and sample data to your question, alongside the expected results.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this might work... -- your query did not include a select distinct, but if this this produces duplicate `TransactionSetUid`s, add the keyword `distinct`...

```
select [distinct] ts.TransactionSetUid      from TransactionSet ts 
   join TransactionHeader th
       on th.TransactionSet = ts.TransactionSet
   join TransactionPayment tp 
       on tp.TransactionHeaderUid = th.TransactionHeaderUid
where not exists
      ( Select * from ServicePayment 
        Where TransactionPaymentUid = tp.TransactionPaymentUid
            and tp.ProcessStatus.value(
                  '(/CPI/@ProcessItem)[1]', 'varchar(50)') IS NULL
            and TransactionStatus = 'Unprocessed')
   Or exists
      ( Select * from ServicePayment 
        Where TransactionPaymentUid = tp.TransactionPaymentUid
            and ts.RuleStatus = 'No-Matched-Payments'
            and tp.ProcessStatus.value(
                  '(/CPI/@ProcessItem)[1]', 'varchar(50)') IS not NULL
            and ts.RuleStatus = 'No-Matched-Payments')
```

Comment: This may need to be a SELECT DISTINCT in order to match the output of the original query.

Comment: Yes, I wondered about that as well, but elected to not include it as the op's original query did not have a `distinct` and he/she implied it was working... I edited my answer to address the issue anyway...